# Ads Not Showing Unity (DebugLogInclude) - (Debug Error)NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm upgraded unity version to 2019.
I've experimented with all versions of 2019 and 2018.3.x & 2018.4xLTS. The ads are working fine in the editor(debugging) .
but not working my ads and not working test ads on build. I'm back to the 2017 Lts version. it's perfect working ads.
please help me.
.................................................................................................................................................................

> ```
> --------- beginning of main
> 05-26 18:36:44.569  2831  2831 I Unity   : onResume
> 05-26 18:36:44.659  2831  2855 D Unity   : SetWindow 0 0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:44.659  2831  2855 D Unity   : SetWindow 0 0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:44.689  2831  2831 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: true
> 05-26 18:36:44.714  2831  2855 D Unity   : [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk
> 05-26 18:36:44.729  2831  2855 I Unity   : SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 2827mb
> 05-26 18:36:44.729  2831  2855 I Unity   : SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
> 05-26 18:36:44.734  2831  2855 I Unity   : ApplicationInfo com.myproject.admobtest version 1.0.5 build 13eebe62-6969-432d-b75a-f7765668df5a
> 05-26 18:36:44.734  2831  2855 I Unity   : Built from '2018.4/staging' branch, Version '2018.4.0f1 (b6ffa8986c8d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
> 05-26 18:36:44.734  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:44.739  2831  2855 D Unity   : Mono path[0] = '/data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'
> 05-26 18:36:44.739  2831  2855 D Unity   : Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed/etc'
> 05-26 18:36:44.739  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
> 05-26 18:36:44.739  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55175
> 05-26 18:36:44.739  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.myproject.admobtest05-26 18:36:44.744  2831  2855 D Unity   : Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.105 [Port] 55175 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 1641182715 [EditorId] 765921864 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(samsung_SM-N910C@192.168.1.105) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
> 05-26 18:36:44.744  2831  2855 D Unity   : Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55175]...
> 05-26 18:36:49.749  2831  2855 D Unity   : Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
> 05-26 18:36:49.749  2831  2855 D Unity   : Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55175]
> 05-26 18:36:49.749  2831  2855 D Unity   : Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56715
> 05-26 18:36:49.834  2831  2855 D Unity   : InitializeScriptEngine OK (0x98795f00)
> 05-26 18:36:49.834  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55175]
> 05-26 18:36:49.854  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
> 05-26 18:36:49.854  2831  2855 D Unity   : AndroidGraphics::Startup window =  0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:49.854  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Checking ES 3.1 support...
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] ES 3.1 support detected
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
> 05-26 18:36:49.859  2831  2855 D Unity   : ANativeWindow: (1920/1080) RequestedResolution: (0/0) RenderingResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (1920/1080)
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : Renderer: Mali-T760
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : Vendor:   ARM
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : Version:  OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-03rel0.e941a8f2c3f57b08b0aebce6b21d4902
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : GLES:     3
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   :  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shade
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : r_pixel_local_storage GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_EXT_copy_image GL_OES_copy_image GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_floa
> 05-26 18:36:49.864  2831  2855 D Unity   : t GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture
> 05-26 18:36:49.869  2831  2855 D Unity   : OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.1 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.1 AEP> ; Context handle -1281165760
> 05-26 18:36:49.869  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:49.874  2831  2855 D Unity   : Requested framebuffer: resolution[1920x1080], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]
> 05-26 18:36:49.874  2831  2855 D Unity   : Created framebuffer: resolution[1920x1080], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0]
> 05-26 18:36:49.874  2831  2855 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x9c90d008
> 05-26 18:36:49.874  2831  2855 D Unity   : Initialize engine version: 2018.4.0f1 (b6ffa8986c8d)
> 05-26 18:36:49.899  2831  2855 D Unity   : Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
> 05-26 18:36:50.144  2831  2855 D Unity   : - Completed reload, in  0.247 seconds
> 05-26 18:36:50.314  2831  2855 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
> 05-26 18:36:50.314  2831  2855 D Unity   : Found 18 native sensors
> 05-26 18:36:50.329  2831  2855 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:36:50.329  2831  2855 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:36:52.389  2831  2855 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 2.132000 ms
> 05-26 18:36:52.389  2831  2855 D Unity   : UUID: 7ef892b3e626cf41 => 2e2d6fe51a045c52efca77662691a4aa
> 05-26 18:36:52.789  2831  2920 D Unity   : Unloading 23 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> 05-26 18:36:52.879  2831  2855 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 39.877000 ms
> 05-26 18:36:52.954  2831  2855 I Unity   : Default clip could not be found in attached animations list.
> 05-26 18:36:53.024  2831  2855 I Unity   : 60 Fps Mode Activated
> 05-26 18:36:53.029  2831  2855 I Unity   : 60 Fps Mode Activated
> 05-26 18:36:53.044  2831  2855 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 41.3 MB.
> 05-26 18:36:53.049  2831  2855 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 41.4 MB.
> 05-26 18:36:53.049  2831  2855 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.049  2831  2855 D Unity   : Unloading 9 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2198.
> 05-26 18:36:53.049  2831  2855 D Unity   : Total: 8.361000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.735000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.125000 ms MarkObjects: 7.111000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.381000 ms)
> 05-26 18:36:53.049  2831  2855 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.074  2831  2855 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:36:53.074  2831  2855 D Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardedAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) [0x00021] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\RewardedAd.cs:35
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.RequestRewardedAds () [0x00008] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:42
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.Start () [0x0000d] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:29
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   : (Filename: E Line: 0)
> 05-26 18:36:53.214  2831  2855 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) [0x00021] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\InterstitialAd.cs:34
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at FullScreenAds.RequestInterstitial () [0x00008] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\FullScreenAds.cs:49
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at FullScreenAds.Start () [0x00001] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\FullScreenAds.cs:32
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   : (Filename: E Line: 0)
> 05-26 18:36:53.234  2831  2855 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.249  2831  2920 D Unity   : Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> 05-26 18:36:53.599  2831  2933 D Unity   : Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
> 05-26 18:36:53.604  2831  2934 D Unity   :   Thread -> id: ffffffff8f940930 -> priority: 1
> 05-26 18:36:53.649  2831  2855 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 42.1 MB.
> 05-26 18:36:53.659  2831  2855 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 42.2 MB.
> 05-26 18:36:53.659  2831  2855 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:36:53.659  2831  2855 D Unity   : Unloading 0 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2209.
> 05-26 18:36:53.659  2831  2855 D Unity   : Total: 8.112000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.688000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.124000 ms MarkObjects: 7.267000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.024000 ms)
> 05-26 18:36:53.659  2831  2855 D Unity   :
> --------- beginning of system
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.ShowRewardedAds () [0x00001] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:147
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00011] in <6f6288095ca042cdaba6cd831bf03eff>:0
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00023] in <6f6288095ca042cdaba6cd831bf03eff>:0
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x0002d] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:66
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00012] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:108
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00008] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\ExecuteEvents.cs:50
> 05-26 18:38:46.299  2831  2855 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEv
> 05-26 18:42:22.984  2831  2831 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: false
> 05-26 18:42:23.109  2831  2831 I Unity   : onPause
> 05-26 18:42:23.764  2831  2855 D Unity   : ASensorManager_destroyEventQueue returned 0
> 05-26 18:42:23.789  2831  2855 I Unity   : ##utp:{"type":"MemoryLeaks","version":2,"phase":"Immediate","time":1558885343793,"processId":2831,"allocatedMemory":22950,"memoryLabels":[{"Default":56},{"NewDelete":15116},{"Thread":8},{"Manager":192},{"GfxDevice":4352},{"Physics":24},{"Serialization":24},{"File":56},{"Terrain":60},{"String":1986},{"DynamicArray":260},{"Utility":360},{"PoolAlloc":4294967236},{"Sprites":32},{"VR":268},{"SceneManager":432},{"SceneLoad":4294967080}]}
> 05-26 18:42:23.899  2831  2831 I Unity   : onDestroy
> 05-26 18:42:49.039  2831  2831 I Unity   : onResume
> 05-26 18:42:49.079  2831  3501 D Unity   : SetWindow 0 0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:49.079  2831  3501 D Unity   : SetWindow 0 0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:49.094  2831  2831 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: true
> 05-26 18:42:49.119  2831  3501 D Unity   : [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk
> 05-26 18:42:49.129  2831  3501 I Unity   : SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 2827mb
> 05-26 18:42:49.129  2831  3501 I Unity   : SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
> 05-26 18:42:49.129  2831  3501 I Unity   : ApplicationInfo com.myproject.admobtest version 1.0.5 build 13eebe62-6969-432d-b75a-f7765668df5a
> 05-26 18:42:49.129  2831  3501 I Unity   : Built from '2018.4/staging' branch, Version '2018.4.0f1 (b6ffa8986c8d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
> 05-26 18:42:49.129  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:49.134  2831  3501 D Unity   : Mono path[0] = '/data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'
> 05-26 18:42:49.134  2831  3501 D Unity   : Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed/etc'
> 05-26 18:42:49.134  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.myproject.admobtest-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
> 05-26 18:42:49.139  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55127
> 05-26 18:42:49.139  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.myproject.admobtest05-26 18:42:49.139  2831  3501 D Unity   : Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.105 [Port] 55127 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 919964927 [EditorId] 765921864 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(samsung_SM-N910C@192.168.1.105) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
> 05-26 18:42:49.139  2831  3501 D Unity   : Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55127]...
> 05-26 18:42:54.144  2831  3501 D Unity   : Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
> 05-26 18:42:54.144  2831  3501 D Unity   : Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55127]
> 05-26 18:42:54.144  2831  3501 D Unity   : Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56927
> 05-26 18:42:54.229  2831  3501 D Unity   : InitializeScriptEngine OK (0x99982f00)
> 05-26 18:42:54.229  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55127]
> 05-26 18:42:54.249  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
> 05-26 18:42:54.249  2831  3501 D Unity   : AndroidGraphics::Startup window =  0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:54.249  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:54.249  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.249  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Checking ES 3.1 support...
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] ES 3.1 support detected
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
> 05-26 18:42:54.254  2831  3501 D Unity   : ANativeWindow: (1920/1080) RequestedResolution: (0/0) RenderingResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (1920/1080)
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : Renderer: Mali-T760
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : Vendor:   ARM
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : Version:  OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-03rel0.e941a8f2c3f57b08b0aebce6b21d4902
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : GLES:     3
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   :  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shade
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : r_pixel_local_storage GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_EXT_copy_image GL_OES_copy_image GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_floa
> 05-26 18:42:54.259  2831  3501 D Unity   : t GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.1 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.1 AEP> ; Context handle -1873203712
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : Requested framebuffer: resolution[1920x1080], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : Created framebuffer: resolution[1920x1080], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0]
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x957e2008
> 05-26 18:42:54.264  2831  3501 D Unity   : Initialize engine version: 2018.4.0f1 (b6ffa8986c8d)
> 05-26 18:42:54.289  2831  3501 D Unity   : Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
> 05-26 18:42:54.534  2831  3501 D Unity   : - Completed reload, in  0.245 seconds
> 05-26 18:42:54.704  2831  3501 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
> 05-26 18:42:54.704  2831  3501 D Unity   : Found 18 native sensors
> 05-26 18:42:54.719  2831  3501 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:42:54.719  2831  3501 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:42:56.769  2831  3501 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 2.466000 ms
> 05-26 18:42:56.769  2831  3501 D Unity   : UUID: 7ef892b3e626cf41 => 2e2d6fe51a045c52efca77662691a4aa
> 05-26 18:42:57.264  2831  3540 D Unity   : Unloading 23 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> 05-26 18:42:57.359  2831  3501 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 46.355000 ms
> 05-26 18:42:57.444  2831  3501 I Unity   : Default clip could not be found in attached animations list.
> 05-26 18:42:57.529  2831  3501 I Unity   : 60 Fps Mode Activated
> 05-26 18:42:57.534  2831  3501 I Unity   : 60 Fps Mode Activated
> 05-26 18:42:57.549  2831  3501 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 41.4 MB.
> 05-26 18:42:57.559  2831  3501 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 41.5 MB.
> 05-26 18:42:57.559  2831  3501 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.559  2831  3501 D Unity   : Unloading 9 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2198.
> 05-26 18:42:57.559  2831  3501 D Unity   : Total: 8.979000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.807000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.140000 ms MarkObjects: 7.562000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.457000 ms)
> 05-26 18:42:57.559  2831  3501 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.579  2831  3501 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001197 / 0.00s ; ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor / Invensense
> 05-26 18:42:57.584  2831  3501 D Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardedAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) [0x00021] in E:\Unity Projects\MyProject\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\RewardedAd.cs:35
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.RequestRewardedAds () [0x00008] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:42
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.Start () [0x0000d] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:29
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   : (Filename: E Line: 0)
> 05-26 18:42:57.754  2831  3501 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) [0x00021] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\InterstitialAd.cs:34
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at FullScreenAds.RequestInterstitial () [0x00008] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\FullScreenAds.cs:49
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at FullScreenAds.Start () [0x00001] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\FullScreenAds.cs:32
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   : (Filename: E Line: 0)
> 05-26 18:42:57.774  2831  3501 E Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:57.789  2831  3540 D Unity   : Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> 05-26 18:42:58.204  2831  3545 D Unity   : Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
> 05-26 18:42:58.204  2831  3546 D Unity   :   Thread -> id: ffffffff8fdff930 -> priority: 1
> 05-26 18:42:58.274  2831  3501 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 42.2 MB.
> 05-26 18:42:58.284  2831  3501 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 42.3 MB.
> 05-26 18:42:58.284  2831  3501 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:42:58.284  2831  3501 D Unity   : Unloading 0 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2209.
> 05-26 18:42:58.284  2831  3501 D Unity   : Total: 9.793000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.255000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.151000 ms MarkObjects: 8.357000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.022000 ms)
> 05-26 18:42:58.284  2831  3501 D Unity   :
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at RewardedAds.ShowRewardedAds () [0x00001] in E:\Unity Projects\Admob\Assets\Scripts\Ads\RewardedAds.cs:147
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00011] in <6f6288095ca042cdaba6cd831bf03eff>:0
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00023] in <6f6288095ca042cdaba6cd831bf03eff>:0
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x0002d] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:66
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00012] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:108
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00008] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\ExecuteEvents.cs:50
> 05-26 18:43:11.339  2831  3501 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEv
> ```

Comment: It would help to see your code, especially where the NullReferenceException is occurring. Without that, any answer to your question would be pure speculation. I would make sure that when upgrading the Unity version, everything in the scene is still hooked up correctly with all inspector fields set as expected.

Comment: scene, prefab, scripts etc is corrected. problem is il2cpp stripping. i found solution. 
GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory.cs script edited and added preserve PreserveAttribute.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Scripting.PreserveAttribute.html

edited script is here; http://pasted.co/65aa0f02

Comment: You should add and accept your answer here, and potentially edit your question to clearly lay out the problem (now that you know what it is), so that anyone else who runs into this issue can benefit from what you've learned.